# T-SQL - Convert/Transpose multiple XML node values to a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have an simple XML field in a table which stores one or more values within it's nodes:

```
<MultiSelect>
  <ItemKey>38</ItemKey>
  <ItemKey>36</ItemKey>
</MultiSelect>
```

How do I query this field in such a way that these values are extracted to a column in the result?

**Source data:**

```
RowKey    Format
-----------------
1         <MultiSelect><ItemKey>40</ItemKey></MultiSelect>
2         <MultiSelect><ItemKey>40</ItemKey><ItemKey>36</ItemKey></MultiSelect>
```

**Aiming for result:**

```
RowKey   ItemKey
----------------
1        40
2        40
2        36
```

I've got close to where I want to be with the query below, but this is only returning the NAME of the XML nodes rather than the values within them:

```
SELECT 
    [RowKey],
    x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS ItemKey

FROM
[tbl_MyDataTable] AS t
    cross apply t.[Format].nodes('MultiSelect/ItemKey') x(y)
```

**Result:**

```
RowKey   ItemKey
----------------
1       ItemKey
2       ItemKey
2       ItemKey
```

Any suggestions greatfully recieved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close - try this (since those are all `INT` numerical values, I'd recommend using `INT` in your XQuery):

```
SELECT 
    [RowKey],
    x.y.value('(.)[1]', 'INT') AS ItemKey
FROM
    dbo.[tbl_MyDataTable] AS t
CROSS APPLY
    t.[Format].nodes('/MultiSelect/ItemKey') x(y)
```

Basically, by selecting `(.)[1]`, you're selecting the **value** of the node - not it's **name** (which is `ItemKey`)